# Most efficient antichess algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, chess

I've been scouring the internet for general algorithms for playing antichess, but can't find anything. Does anyone have any ideas about how to win at antichess?

Answer (score 1):

All game-playing algorithms are basically http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning with different board-scoring functions.

You can google for antichess board-scoring functions.

Also according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichess you shouldn't make any of the starting moves of 1.d4, 1.e4, 1.d3, 1.Nc3, 1.Nf3, 1.f4, 1.h4, 1.b4, or 1.h3; they lose you the game.